# Can't to retrieve all IDs of the drawables – Android

Tags: java, android, collections, resources, android-drawable

I have silly problem and I can't find out where is problem.
I want to retrieve all ID of drawable elements, but I get only first id of element.
my code:

```
images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String img = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("img_eq"));
                    String[] parts = img.split(",");

                    for (String part : parts) {

                        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(part , "drawable", getPackageName());

                        images.add(resID);
                    }
```

I've checked the array "parts" has all elements, but ArrayList has only one id.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: so you want to retrieve ID's of all drawables from drawable folder?

Comment: I think you can use reflection API on R.drawable class and access all static variables... isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay...
Cause of my problem was " " in string array.
That is why I got null instead of element id.